# sql server 2008 Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-administration

i have a stored procedure as follows:

```
USE [cheminova]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Firstdistil]    Script Date: 10/30/2014 11:55:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Pragya>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Firstdistil] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    --   @StartDate varchar(50)=Null,
       --@EndDate varchar(50)=Null
       @SDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    declare @StartDate varchar(50)
    declare @EndDate varchar(50)
    set @EndDate=CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(month,@SDate))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(DAY,@SDate))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YEAR,@SDate))+' 06:00:00'
    set @StartDate=CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(month,DATEADD(day,-1,@SDate)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(day,-1,@SDate)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(day,-1,@SDate)))+' 06:00:00'
    Begin
    --table to store data of each tag for a day
    create table #tempval
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        tagname varchar(100),
        [timestamp] Varchar(50),
        tagval varchar(50),
        quality varchar(20)
    )
    create table #tempval1
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        tagname varchar(100),
        [timestamp] Varchar(50),
        tagval varchar(50),
        quality varchar(20)
    )
    create table #tempval2
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        tagname varchar(100),
        [timestamp] Varchar(50),
        tagval varchar(50),
        quality varchar(20)
    )
    create table #tempval3
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        tagname varchar(100),
        [timestamp] Varchar(50),
        tagval varchar(50),
        quality varchar(20)
    )
    --table to store average of each tag for a day
    create table #tagavg
    (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    avgtag float
    )
                create table #temp1
                (
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                --[Timestamp] varchar(50),
                [Value][float] NULL
                )
                create table #temp2
                (
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                --[Timestamp] varchar(50),
                [Value][float] NULL
                )
                create table #temp3
                (
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                --[Timestamp] varchar(50),
                [Value][float] NULL
                )
                create table #temp4
                (
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                --[Timestamp] varchar(50),
                [Value][float] NULL
                )
                create table #temp5
                (
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                --[Timestamp] Datetime,
                [Value][float] NULL
                )
    create table #tempdigival
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [timestamp] varchar(30),
        tagval varchar(30)
    )

    create table #tempsum
    (
        tagval varchar(30),
        calevent float
    )

    create table #tagtemp
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [timestamp] datetime,
        tagname varchar(200),
        descrip varchar(200),
        unit varchar(10),
        tagval varchar(38),
        calevent float
    )
    create table #totalizervalue
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        tagname varchar(200),
        waqt varchar(30),
        tagval varchar(30)
    )
    create table #FinalResult
        (
           [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                tag1 float,
                tag2 float,
                tag3 float,
                tag4 float,
                tag5 float,
                tag6 float
        )
    --to store reading
    --select @StartDate as startdate,@EndDate as enddate
     DECLARE @SQL as varchar(1000)
    Declare @Tagname varchar(300)
    Declare @tagVal float
    Declare @calval float
    declare @avgtag float
    declare @X1 float
    declare @Y1 float
    declare @Z1 float
    declare @X2 float
    declare @Y2 float
    declare @Z2 float
    declare @X3 float
    declare @Y3 float
    declare @Z3 float
    declare @X4 float
    declare @Y4 float
    declare @Z4 float
    declare @X5 float
    declare @Y5 float
    declare @Z5 float
    declare @X6 float
    declare @Y6 float
    declare @Z6 float
    declare @X7 float
    declare @Y7 float
    declare @Z7 float
    declare @X8 float
    declare @Y8 float
    declare @Z8 float
    declare @query varchar(500)
    declare @starttime varchar(30)
    declare @endtime varchar(30)
    declare @coltagname varchar(300)
    declare @coltimestamp datetime
    declare @colavg varchar(38)
    declare @prevtime varchar(30)
    declare @currtime varchar(30)
    declare @breakflag int
    declare @firsttimeflag int
    set @firsttimeflag=0
    declare @final float
    declare @initial float
    declare @event float
    Declare @digitalsql varchar(1000)
    set @final=0
    set @initial=0
     set @SQL ='SELECT tagname, timestamp , value,Quality FROM OPENQUERY(chemhist,''
     set  StartTime = '''''+ @StartDate +''''', EndTime = '''''+ @EndDate +''''', rowcount=0, samplingmode=RawByTime    
     SELECT tagname, timestamp  ,value,quality FROM ihRawData 
     WHERE tagname =''''ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1302'''' '')'
     INSERT INTO #tempval1 EXEC(@SQL)
     Set @Tagname='ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1302'
        --Select @Tagname as TagName, [timestamp],CAST(tagval as float)as TagValue,
        --Cast(tagval as float)*11.08 as CalValue ,quality from
        --#tempval1 ORDER BY tagname, [timestamp]
        select top 1 @X1= Cast(tagval as float) from #tempval1 order by ID asc
        --select @X1 as FirstVal        
        select top 1 @Y1=Cast(tagval as Float) from #tempval1 order by ID Desc
        --Select @Y1 as SecondVal
        set @Z1=(@Y1-@X1)*11.08
        Insert into #temp1 values (@Z1)
        --SELECT @Z1 as LI1603 from #temp1

     set @sql ='SELECT tagname, timestamp , value,Quality FROM OPENQUERY(chemhist,''
     set  StartTime = '''''+ @StartDate +''''', EndTime = '''''+ @EndDate +''''', rowcount=0, samplingmode=Calculated    
     SELECT tagname, timestamp  ,value,quality FROM ihRawData 
     WHERE tagname =''''ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1304'''' '')'
     INSERT INTO #tempval2 EXEC(@SQL)
       /*Select  @Tagname as TagName,[timestamp],CAST(tagval as float)as TagValue,
        Cast(tagval as float)*6.02 as CalValue ,quality from
     #tempval2 ORDER BY tagname, [timestamp]*/
     select top 1 @X2= Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval2 order by ID asc
        select top 1 @Y2=Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval2 order by ID desc
        set @Z2=(@Y2-@X2)*6.02
        Insert into #temp2 values (@Z2)
        --SELECT @Z2 as LI1604 from #temp2

     set @SQL ='SELECT tagname, timestamp , value,Quality FROM OPENQUERY(chemhist,''
     set  StartTime = '''''+ @StartDate +''''', EndTime = '''''+ @EndDate +''''', rowcount=0, samplingmode=RawByTime    
     SELECT tagname, timestamp  ,value,quality FROM ihRawData 
     WHERE tagname =''''ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1403'''' '')'
     INSERT INTO #tempval3 EXEC(@SQL)
     SET @Tagname='ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1403' 
       /* Select @Tagname as TagName,[timestamp],CAST(tagval as float)as TagValue,
        Cast(tagval as float)*4.80 as CalValue ,quality from
        #tempval3 ORDER BY tagname, [timestamp]*/
        select top 1 @X3= Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval3 order by ID asc
        --select @X3 as FirstValue
        Select top 1 @Y3=Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval3 order by ID Desc
        --select @Y3 as secondvalue
        set @Z3=(@Y3-@X3)*4.80
        Insert into #temp3 values (@Z3)
        --SELECT @Z3 as LI1607 from #temp3

        set @query='select * from openquery(chemhist,''set StartTime="'+@starttime+'",EndTime="'+@endtime+'",SamplingMode=RawByTime,RowCount=0 select timestamp,value from ihrawdata where tagname=ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.P65'')'
        insert into #tempdigival exec(@query)
        select @breakflag= COUNT(*) from #tempdigival where tagval=1
        set @query='select * from openquery(chemhist,''set StartTime="'+@starttime+'",EndTime="'+@endtime+'",SamplingMode=RawByTime,RowCount=0 select tagname,timestamp,value from ihrawdata where tagname=ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LI1505'')'     
        insert into #totalizervalue exec(@query)
        --take lost time from manual
        if (@breakflag>0)       
        begin
            declare C1 cursor
            for select timestamp from #tempdigival where tagval=1
            open C1
            fetch next from C1 into @currtime
            while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
            begin
                if (@firsttimeflag=0)
                begin
                    set @firsttimeflag=1
                select @initial=cast(tagval as float)from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)=CONVERT(datetime2,dateadd(SECOND,10, CONVERT(datetime2,@starttime)))
                    select top 1 @final=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)<=CONVERT(datetime2,@currtime) order by waqt desc
                    set @final=(@final-@initial) 
                    set @event=@final * 10
                    set @colavg=CONVERT(varchar,@event)
                    insert into #tempsum values(@colavg,@final) 
                    set @prevtime=@currtime
                end
                else
                begin
                    select top 1 @initial=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)>=CONVERT(datetime2,@prevtime)
                    select top 1 @final=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)<=CONVERT(datetime2,@currtime) order by waqt desc
                    set @final=(@final-@initial)
                    set @colavg=CONVERT(varchar,@final)
                    insert into #tempsum values(@colavg,@final) 
                    set @prevtime=@currtime
                end
                fetch next from C1 into @currtime
            end
            select top 1 @initial=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)>=CONVERT(datetime2,@prevtime)
            select top 1 @final=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)<=CONVERT(datetime2,@enddate) order by waqt desc
            set @final=(@final-@initial)
            set @event=@final * 10
            set @colavg=CONVERT(varchar,@event)
            insert into #tempsum values(@colavg,@final) 
            close C1
            deallocate C1
            select @colavg=SUM(CAST(tagval as float)) from #tempsum
            --truncate table #tempsum
            set @coltagname='ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LIC1503'
            set @coltimestamp=CONVERT(datetime,@endtime)
            insert into #tagtemp values(@coltimestamp,@coltagname,'PDS slurry Flow Totaliser - 9A','m3',@colavg,@final)
        end
        else
        begin
            select @initial=cast(tagval as float)from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)=CONVERT(datetime2,dateadd(SECOND,10, CONVERT(datetime2,@starttime)))
            select top 1 @final=cast(tagval as float) from #totalizervalue where CONVERT(datetime2,waqt)<=CONVERT(datetime2,@enddate) order by waqt desc    
            set @final=(@final-@initial)
            set @event=@final * 10
            set @colavg=CONVERT(varchar,@event)
            set @coltagname='ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.LI1505'
            set @coltimestamp=CONVERT(datetime,@endtime)
            insert into #tagtemp values(@coltimestamp,@coltagname,'PDS slurry Flow Totaliser - 9A','m3',@colavg,@final)
        end
        --SELECT @Z4 as LI1608 from #temp4 

     set @SQL ='SELECT tagname, timestamp , value,Quality FROM OPENQUERY(chemhist,''
     set  StartTime = '''''+ @StartDate +''''', EndTime = '''''+ @EndDate +''''', rowcount=0, samplingmode=RawByTime    
     SELECT tagname, timestamp  ,value,quality FROM ihRawData 
     WHERE tagname =''''ADMIN-PC.Channel5.Device1.FIQ1302'''' '')'
     INSERT INTO #tempval EXEC(@SQL)
     --SET @Tagname='ADMIN-PC.Chem.Device1.LI1609'
     --   Select @Tagname,[timestamp],CAST(tagval as float)as TagValue,
     --   Cast(tagval as float)*73.30 as CalValue ,quality from
     --#tempval ORDER BY tagname, [timestamp]
     --select @calval=Cast (tagval as Float)*73.30 from #tempval
     --   Insert into #tagtemp values (@calval,@tagVal)
        select top 1 @X5= Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval order by ID asc
        --select @X5 as FirstValue
        Select top 1 @Y5=Cast (tagval as Float) from #tempval order by ID Desc
        --select @Y5 as secondvalue
        set @Z5=(@Y5-@X5)*73.30
        Insert into #temp5 values (@Z5)
        --SELECT @Z5 as LI1609 from #temp5
     END
     set @avgtag=cast((isnull(@Z1,0)+isnull(@Z2,0)+isnull(@Z3,0)+isnull(@Z4,0)) as float)/cast((nullif((@Z5),0)) as float)
     insert into #tagavg values (@avgtag)
     --select * from #tagavg
     --inner join on table
     Begin
     insert into #finalResult select isnull(t1.Value,0) as  R_21LT,isnull(t2.Value,0) as  R_22LT,isnull(t3.Value,0) as R_24LT, isnull(t4.calevent,0) as B_22LT,isnull(t5.Value,0) as DETA_FIQ ,isnull(t6.avgtag,0) as avgtag from #temp1 as t1
     Inner join #temp2 as t2
     on t2.ID=t1.ID
     Inner join #temp3 as t3
     on t3.ID=t2.ID
     Inner join #tagtemp as t4
     on t4.ID=t3.ID
     inner join #temp5 as t5
     on t5.ID=t4.ID
     inner join #tagavg as t6
     on t6.ID=t5.ID
     select tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6 from #FinalResult
     End

END
```

and i have another stored procedure as follows

```
USE [cheminova]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_FinalYieldtemp]    Script Date: 10/30/2014 10:22:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FinalYieldtemp] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @sdate datetime

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SET @sdate=convert(varchar (10),@sdate,103)
declare @sql as varchar(1000)
Begin
        create table #Temp1
        (
           [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                tag1 float,
                tag2 float,
                tag3 float,
                tag4 float,
                tag5 float,
                tag6 float
        )
END
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @SQL ='SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=ADMIN-PC;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC [cheminova].[dbo].[SP_Firstdistil] "'+convert(varchar(20),@sdate,103)+'" '')'
--select @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
--INSERT into  #Temp1 EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

and i execute SP_FinalYieldtemp as follows:

```
exec SP_FinalYieldtemp '2014-10-29'
```

but i m getting following error

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure SP_Firstdistil, Line 0
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

what i have done here is, i have called SP_Firstdistil procedure with parameter @sdate in SP_FinalYieldtemp in stored procedure.

when i executed SP_Firstdistil procedure, it gave me proper output. 
i m very confused in SET @SQL statement in SP_FinalYieldtemp procedure.
plz help to resolve it

Comment: this is not the problem. i m getting error in SET @SQL ='SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=ADMIN-PC;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC [cheminova].[dbo].[SP_Firstdistil] "'+convert(varchar(20),@sdate,103)+'" '')'
EXEC (@SQL) which is in SP_FinalYieldtemp procedure

Answer (score 1):

103 is an ambiguous style. If you *must* continue with this string-heavy style, at least use unambiguous styles in your [conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx).

The unambiguous styles are 112 (for just a date) and 126 (for a date and time). So:

```
SET @SQL ='SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',
''Server=ADMIN-PC;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC [cheminova].[dbo].[SP_Firstdistil] "'+
    convert(varchar(20),@sdate,112)+'" '')'
```

Although I'd also recommend switching to using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which allows you to pass parameters using there natural types rather than converting everything into strings.

---

Other points from comments, not directly relating to the problem/solution:

1) Using this many temporary tables is usually a sign that you're doing it wrong<sup>TM</sup> - it feels like you've broken the task down into lots of little procedural steps. Instead, in SQL, what you should try to do is describe the entire task you want to do (rather than how to do it) and let the query optimizer attempt to find the best way to achieve that result.

2) Avoid using the `sp_` prefix when [naming procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

3) Stop doing everything by string manipulation. For instance, this:

```
set @EndDate=CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(month,@SDate))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(DAY,@SDate))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YEAR,@SDate))+' 06:00:00'
```

which appears to be attempting to create "today at 6am" could be replaced by:

```
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20000101',@SDate),'2001-01-01T06:00:00')
```

Which just performs two simple pieces of date arithmetic rather than constructing an (again) ambiguous date format and hoping that SQL Server converts it back into a `datetime` correctly.

4) And similarly, once that date has been constructed, you can simply `DATEADD(day,-1,@EndDate)` to produce "yesterday at 6am" rather than doing either of those conversions *again*.